# Partial function application in Scala for arbitrary input arguments

Tags: scala, function, variadic-functions, partial-application, arity

I am wondering whether the following is possible in Scala:

Given some vector `x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)` in `R^n` and a function `f` that maps `R^n` to `R`, I would like to replicate this concept in Scala. The idea of Scala's partial function/currying should hold here (i.e. when applying a single value `x_i`, return a function that is defined only for a subset of its input domain). For example, when n = 2 define `f(x, y) = sin(x + y)`, then trivially, `f(2, y) = sin(2 + y)`.

However, the dimension (n > 0)  may vary from case to case and may even be provided in input.

Partial application for n = 2 is:

```
def leftPartialFunction(f: (Double, Double) => Double)(x: Double): Double => Double = f(x, _)
```

but how can this be generalized for arbitrary n?
For example, how can I apply the function in position `i`?
Something like this I assume would not work:

```
def partialFunction(f: IndexedSeq[Double] => Double)(xi: Double): IndexedSeq[Double] => Double =  .... // cannot work well with indexed seq as they are not "disjoint"
```

Comment: `leftPartialFunction` looks like currying `((Double, Double) => Double) => Double => Double => Double`

Comment: @DmytroMitin indeed it is

Comment: Are you trying to define `((A1, ..., An) => B) => A1 => ... => An => B` for arbitrary `n`?

Comment: "Abstracting over arity" https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity

Comment: What do you mean by *"indexed seq are not "disjoint""*?

Comment: To give a bit more context, I am trying to write a numerical integrator for a function of N dimensions. Taking for example the simple Trapezoidal Rule, we can apply recursively the 1D Trapezoidal Formula to obtain a "functional implementation".
In this case the 1D Trapezoidal Formula takes ```Double => Double``` and yields ```Double```, and we recursively call this function to lower the dimensions of the N dimensional Trapezoidal Rule, there for going (for example) ```(Double, Double, Double) => Double``` to ```(Double, Double) => Double``` to ```Double => Double``` ...

Comment: However, generalizing to such procedure for arbitrary N would require a data structure such as a ```Seq```, which seems unfeasible for this purpose. Another level of complexity is that each recursive call, the function ```f``` changes type (i.e. goes from ```(Double, Double, Double) => ... ``` to ```(Double, Double) => ... ``` etc... )

Answer (score 1):

Try the following implementation of `partialFunction`:

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil, Nat, Succ}
import shapeless.ops.function.{FnFromProduct, FnToProduct}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{At, Drop, Prepend, Take}

def partialFunction[N <: Nat, F, X,
                    L <: HList, Y, L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList, L3 <: HList
                   ](i: N)(f: F)(xi: X)(implicit
  fnToProduct: FnToProduct.Aux[F, L => Y],
  at: At.Aux[L, N, X],
  take: Take.Aux[L, N, L1],
  drop: Drop.Aux[L, Succ[N], L2],
  prepend: Prepend.Aux[L1, L2, L3],
  fnFromProduct: FnFromProduct[L3 => Y],
  take1: Take.Aux[L3, N, L1],
  drop1: Drop.Aux[L3, N, L2],
  prepend1: Prepend.Aux[L1, X :: L2, L],
): fnFromProduct.Out =
  fnFromProduct(l3 => fnToProduct(f)(prepend1(take1(l3), xi :: drop1(l3))))
```

Testing:

```
import shapeless.Nat._1

val f: (Int, Boolean, Double) => String = (i, b, d) => s"i=$i, b=$b, d=$d"

f(1, true, 2.0) // i=1, b=true, d=2.0

val f1 = partialFunction(_1)(f)(true)

f1: ((Int, Double) => String)

f1(1, 2.0) // i=1, b=true, d=2.0
```

You can also write `partialFunction(Nat(1))(f)(true)` instead of `partialFunction(_1)(f)(true)`.